# How to delete cookies using javascript after certain time

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to delete a the value cookie that I created after a certain interval. Lets say after 10 second I want the cookie gone

```
function fullday()
{
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML="1 day";
    document.cookie="day="+1;
    document.cookie.setMaxAge(0);
}
```

This is the code above. I'm coding in PHP right now and then when I try to destroy cookie from PHP it works fine, however I need to pass the cookie's value in javascript so now im stuck with it and cannot destroy it.

Comment: Why not just set the expire date to 10 mins from the moment you create it?

Comment: Its working fine when its in php but doesnt work when i passed the cookie to java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to delete a cookie you need to set the expiry date to something in the past. A function that does this would be for example:

```
var delete_cookie = function(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};
```

Then to delete a cookie named "cookie" just do.

```
delete_cookie('cookie');
```

Comment: how long would it take to delete this a couple of minutes or in an instant the query is run?

Answer (score 2):

pass cookie name at "key"

```
 _generatePrefix: function()
    {
        return '__session:' + this._id + ':';
    }
  _cookieCache: undefined,
function cookie clear(key)
  {    
    document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    delete this._cookieCache[key]
  }
```

call this function when u need clear specific cookie

if u want clear all cookie use this

```
   _generatePrefix: function()
    {
        return '__session:' + this._id + ':';
    }
     _cookieCache: undefined, 
     function clearall()
    {
        for (var i in this._cookieCache) {
            document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + i + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }
        this._cookieCache = {};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use it like this

```
var date1 = new Date();
date1.setTime(date.getTime()+(10*1000));
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

document.cookie = "day="+1+expires;
```

this will expire the cookie after 10 seconds.

Comment: will this exipre the cookie in 10 seconds or minutes

Answer (score 0):

The first question to ask is why you didn't just the cookie expiry time when you created the cookie?

The second question to ask is how did you create the cooklie? Via Javacript or PHP?

You can't retrieve anything other than the cookie value in javascript - hence if you want to know how old a cookie is, then you'd need to embed that information in the value - however if the cookie is set from PHP, and with a TTL of 10 seconds, you're going to run in clock sync issues - you'd need to generate javascript to create the timestamped cookie from serverside rather than callnig setcookie directly.